# How can I tag a menu item as visited for each unique user?

Tags: customization, menus

I'm creating a learning platform and I have a separate menu for different sections.
What I'd like to do is mark these menu items once the unique registered user has seen it.

Like:

```
.menu-item li{
[basic-css-menu-style]
}
.menu-item li if $user_visited {
[checkmark-css-menu-style]
}
```

This is to show the user that they have completed the section. I don't want to restrict them from seeing the menu item again. Just add a style or a word/checkmark etc. to show they're done with a particular section, after visiting it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS. Get the class of the  element in the menu item and add this css:

```
[class of the menu item]:visited {your own css}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'll play around with it. I can link the next section on a button, and then have it appear as anything other than :visited will be hidden.

Thanks for that. Didn't think about it. I can easily do this by sectioning it off tediously. Like Section 1 (1 page, ~10 paginated), button to next section, different menu with marker on Section 1 to reveal status as viewed. But that's like.. so much repetition.

Comment: If this question helped, could you please accept my answer? If not, do you have any questions?

Comment: Sorry it didn't really help. What I can do is make the menu hidden with display:none, then go to each individual item and do something like `.page-id-1688.paged-2 #menu-aml #menu-item-1654 {
    display: block;
}`
Problem is when I do this the menus will always look like that. What I'd like to do is make the menu completely visible once the registered user has gone through them all.